# Remove CSS stylesheet from DOM

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am styling a website. The core comes from a third party developer and also includes some css. There is one CSS file that really messes up the website. Therefore I would like to remove it from the DOM.
I tried using jQuery:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="./admin/include/WantToRemove.css?rev=1634758035"]').remove();
```

and in theory it works fine. However every once in a while the rev ID is changed by the third party developer and the code stops working. The name of the .css before the rev does not change.
Something like

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="./admin/include/WantToRemove.css"]').remove();
```

did not work for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't remove the CSS, override it with your own styling rules. Although this is a very odd thing to be doing; just remove the CSS reference from your own source code.

Comment: The stylesheet I want to remove is 20000 lines of code. With endless !important statements, and updated on a regular basis. So super messy when coding my own CSS. So I just want it to be removed. Of course overwriting would most of the time be the better option, but I started overwriting and gave up...

Answer (score 0):

`~=` will match elements that have [the passed value surrounded by whitespace](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/). The  `WantToRemove.css` doesn't end in whitespace - it instead ends with `?rev=someNumbers`, so that must be causing the selector to fail.

Use `*=` instead, so that the value is found anywhere inside the attribute, rather than requiring it to be matched as a "word" (with whitespace on one of the ends).

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href*="./admin/include/WantToRemove.css"]').remove();
```

To avoid jankyness, try to run this *as soon as possible* after the unwanted stylesheet appears, before the browser has a chance to paint, otherwise your users may see the website styles blink on pageload, which doesn't look good.

If you're able to run code before the CSS element appears, you could also use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead, and `.remove()` the `<link>` when the observer detects it.

Comment: Yes. I would be able to place the code before the CSS element appears. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a working solution with MutationObserver. Help here would be appreciated.